# How to convert JS code to React by onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave or something better

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
const w_phones = document.querySelectorAll('.w-nav__btn');

w_phones.forEach(w_phone => {
  const item_data = w_phone.dataset.phone
  const item = document.getElementById(item_data);

  console.log(item)

  w_phone.onmouseover = function () {
    item.classList.add('active')
  };

  w_phone.onmouseout = function () {
    item.classList.remove('active')
  };
});
```

I need to convert this code to React.
Code of buttons look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwUvM.png)

Class active must be here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyF9U.png) "w-phones__item w-phones__item--1 active" and on 2, 3

How to fix this? [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdNVi.jpg)

Comment: Close but i when i hover on button 2 w-phones__item--2 get class active and when hover on button 3 w-phones__item--3

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for javascript if all you want to do is add a css class.  The `:hover` pseuedoselector will only take effect when the user is hovered over the .w-nav__ and you can apply the style to the phone items below it like this.

```css
.w-nav__btn:hover .w-phone__item {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: Sry, forget add another class

Comment: Updated solution. You don't need to add a bunch of classes just use css.